# Htaccess multilanguage mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, redirect

Ok, I've wasted a lot of time trying to figure this out but the more I'm trying to learn about rewriting rules, the less I seem to understand what's going on. I need to fix some rewriting rules for a codeigniter based project.

The application is a multilanguage CMS that basically works with modules, pages and posts and in a `.htaccess` file I need to check if the url is a page or a post and redirect to a appropriate controller.

So far in my `.htaccess` file i have the following:

```
    #if I'm on the homepage and i have a language id
    RewriteCond $1 ^([a-z]{2})/?$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?homepage/index/$1 [PT,L]

    #if module - this works ok when there is no language id
    RewriteCond $1 ^(gallery|post|products)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [PT,L]

    # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL - page controller
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page/show/$0 [PT,L]
```

With the code above, if I enter

```
http://mydomain.com/gallery/something/9
```

everything is fine and dandy, dut if I add a language id like so:

```
http://mydomain.com/en/gallery/something/9
```

it doesn't work anymore, and I get a page not found/404 error from the page controller (redirect at the end of .htaccess).

So let's say that i have urls that can look something like this:

```
    http://mydomain.com/gallery/something/9       
    http://mydomain.com/en/gallery/something/25
    http://mydomain.com/fr/post/something/31
```

I need to somehow redirect those urls to

```
     http://mydomain.com/gallery/something/9        
     http://mydomain.com/en/gallery/somethingelse/25
     http://mydomain.com/fr/post/somethingelse/31
```

Notice that sometimes I have language id, and sometimes I don't. 
Is this something that I should be doing by using htaccess? Is Codeigniter routing a better alternative?
Thank you for any help Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
RewriteCond $1 ^[^/]*/?(gallery|post|products)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I've managed to somehow kind of make it work with Codeigniter routes in the meantime. I've tried your code, and it does partially work, the language id is still giving me problems. I've decided that CI routing is good enough...for now :). Thanks again